# How to remove unsafe-eval from chrome extension's content_security_policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have removed all usages of `eval` and and `new Function` from a legacy chrome extension, that I am mantaining. How should I update the `content_security_policy` section in my `manifest.json`?

Currently it looks like this:

```
{
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://app.xyz.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

If I understand the CSP in chrome extension correctly, after I removed all `eval` and `new Function` calls from the extension code I may remove the `unsafe-eval` from the `manifest.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Eval` and related functions are disabled. [But,] the policy against `eval()` and its relative `new Function(String)` can be relaxed by adding `'unsafe-eval'` to your policy

This means that code using `eval` and `new Function` will only work if you have

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

in your manifest.

Try taking this line out of your manifest and running your extension. If everything still works as expected, then you are safe to remove this policy from your manifest, as you have removed all disabled functions correctly.

---

[Link to CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

Note: you must remove all the necessary functions related to `eval` (as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSEval)).

> Code like the following does not work:

```
window.setTimeout("alert('hi')", 10);
window.setInterval("alert('hi')", 10);
```